# Access 2007: Designing a form to show multiple years of salary, how?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am designing a form to show employees' salary information. I need the form to show salary for years 2007 - 2013 in addition to their other personal info.

The form should look like this:

```
 Name   Department   Sub Department

        2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
 Salary  x
 Bonus   y
 Total  x+y

 Various stats:  
 Calls Stats 2013      [a]  [c]
 Marketing Stats 2013  [b]  [d]
 Sales Rank 2011       [x]
 Sales Rank 2012       [y]
 Sales Rank 2013       [z]
```

I have tried *everything* to get the years to work properly but to no avail. I have tried making one large query. I have tried making multiple queries and plugging them in.

My tables are:

- EmpTable
- CompensationTable
- DepartmentTable
- StatsTable

CompTable and StatsTable have a **year** column so each year has different salary/stats.

What are the steps to setting up a form like this? I have tried several things but none of them are working. I want it all to be on one page so I don't want to use split form unless I really have to.

**EDIT:** Schema:

```
   EmpTable       CompTable        DeptTable                StatsTable
                  PK CompID                                PK StatsID
   PK ID   ------>FK ID   -----> PK/FK ID (From emp) ----> FK ID (From emp)
      Name           Year           Dept                      Year 
      Etc.           Salary                                   Rank
```

Solutions I have tried:

1. Making one large query with no normalization. For example it has columns for each year. 
             *Used to work but doesn't work now because I fixed normalization in my tables.*
2. Making one large query with multiple queries. Each individual query for each year. For example, 2013 Comp Query + 2012 Comp Query all into one big query.
              *Doesn't work because too many fields. (more than 127)*

Comment: Schema of your tables would be helpful, also add solutions you have tried.

Comment: You could create a sub form in pivot table view to get the look that you want and add that to the top of your form without having to split it.

Comment: What you're looking for is a crosstab query

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a crosstab query.

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html  is a good starting source.

If you use the Access query builder you can easily generate the query you need.  It'll be a similar experience to making a pivot table in Excel.

You will have to select:

Years as `Column Heading` under `Crosstab`

Employee as `Row Heading` under `Crosstab`

Salary as `Value` under `Crosstab`

Salary as `Sum` under `Total`

Will roughly look something like this

```
TRANSFORM Sum(CompensationTable.Salary) AS SumOfSalary
SELECT EmpTable.EmpName
FROM ((EmpTable INNER JOIN StatsTable ON EmpTable.ID = StatsTable.ID) INNER JOIN DepartmentTable ON EmpTable.ID = DepartmentTable.ID) INNER JOIN CompensationTable ON EmpTable.ID = CompensationTable.ID
GROUP BY EmpTable.EmpName
PIVOT StatsTable.Yr;
```